# span class in link with class CakePHP Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a link that has a button class.

I need to place an icon in the button, so the span tag is needed to do that, but I can't give span the class. I tried like this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

This is my link

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
           $this->Html->tag('span',__('Crear Pacientes',true)),
           array('controller' => 'pacientes', 'action' => 'add'),
           array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-info')
      );
?>
```

How can I add the class to the span tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `'escape'=>false` option

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link(
        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>',
        array(
            'controller'=>'pacientes',
            'action'=>'add'
        ),
        array(
            'escape'=>false,
            'class'=>'btn btn-info'
            'escape'=>false  //NOTICE THIS LINE ***************
        )
    ); 
?>
```

[see Explanation Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964599/how-to-write-html-tag-in-cakephp-link)

or, add `array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-search')`

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->tag(
            'span',
            __('Crear Pacientes',true),
            array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-search') //NOTICE THIS LINE ***************
        ),
        array(
            'controller'=>'pacientes',
            'action'=>'add'
        ),
        array(
            'escape'=>false,
            'class'=>'btn btn-info'
        )
    ); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works... But just a little thing, Why the Font in the Button change? Is there a way to preserve the css font of boostrap?

Comment: You can make additional class  in **main.css**  `.btnfont{font-family: time new roman;}` and add it  to span `class="glyphicon glyphicon-search btnfont"`